# How to display not found page on not define slug ? / React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How I can display something like page not found in a define route path, but with not valid slug?
Example:

I have defined route with path `/about`:

```
<Switch>
   // other routes 
   <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
   <Route component={PageNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

When I visit link like this :
[image]

I got about page component, but I have the wrong slug (or not defined) after route (in my case `/about`), how to catch that and display not found page in example code above.

Thanks. o/

Comment: Hey Milosh, I was wondering if my answer was helpful to you. If it answered your question I would appreciate you marking it as answered so others can see this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you still get to the About page is because you're still matching the path. If you only want to go to a route if the path match is exact, you can pass the `exact` flag to the Route: `<Route exact path='/about' component={AboutPage} />`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood you fully, but are you aiming to achieve something like in [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) exact & strict example?

So for `localhost:3000/about` you'd see the about page, but for `localhost:3000/about/sth` you'd get redirected to `/`?